# Import list of songs into Apple Music

Tags: macos, itunes, music, apple-music

### Import list of songs into Apple Music

---

**Context:**

---

Essentially, I've been writing down a list of songs in my note app on my Macbook Pro (more specifically, OneNote) which I like - just the name, because usually I'll know the artist and recognise the song based on the name. It's something like 100 songs long.

I just got Apple Music, and I want to create a huge playlist with all the songs on the list - only I don't want to add them one at a time.

---

**Question:**

---

Is there some way I can import a list of song names into Apple Music and mass add them into one playlist as opposed to individually adding them? Some way for apple music to recognise the song and add it?

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. 
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/)

Answer (score 1):

Apple Music import expects a structured list with a key that matches your song with the geographic region in which you are licensed to play the content. (The song is licensed and identified differently in the 150 or so “stores” …)

If typing them is slow for you in Apple Music, you could enable Siri and use that to add three of the songs to a playlist:

- Hey Siri, play Dissolved by Jimanica
- Hey Siri, play Wrinkle by Miles Davis
- Hey Siri, play Vitamin C by Can

If you get the correct version of the correct song (unlikely with Jimanica, lots of versions of wrinkle but the last should work easily), next use Siri to add these to your playlist. You will need to create this playlist before Siri can add a track.

- Hey Siri, add this to my huge playlist

Once you have three songs, you can export that not yet huge playlist to a text file and check out the data structure.

Whatever tool or automation or service you use will need to make up all those details for the import or selection to work.

My hunch is you’ll want to chip away at these by hand and won’t save any time automating it, but perhaps your diction or songs are easier to add then mine. I use Siri to add these songs to my “second listen” playlist as I find them rather than dump it to a text file / note since it’s faster for me than trying to import them later.